# nodeos lib doesn't found

Tags: nodeos, ubuntu, build

I tried both ubuntu16.04 and ubuntu18.04 with version 1.8.4 installed on Debian 4.9.144-2 (2019-01-21),
and always get below error when start `nodeos`:

nodeos: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: version `OPENSSL_1.0.2' not found (required by nodeos)

Anyone can help me to figure the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have to Install OpenSSL first.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openssl
```

Comment: openssl is already installed, but the version seems not matched

Comment: I am working on debian

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install libssl1.0.2
```

If your issue is not solved by above command, you had better build openssl by yourself.